# Social Networking Friends table - Explain Plan - Error Failed to enable constraints error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a below table structure for friends table

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
CREATE TABLE `my_friends` (
  `first_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `second_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `request_sent` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_approved` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

**DATA**

```
insert into `my_friends` values (4,1,1,null,null);
insert into `my_friends` values (7,8,1,null,null);
insert into `my_friends` values (1,7,1,null,null);
insert into `my_friends` values (2,7,1,null,null);
insert into `my_friends` values (4,2,1,null,null);
```

To get all the friends for user id "1" , I am running the below query

**QUERY TO GET FRIENDS**

```
SELECT  first_user_id user_id, second_user_id friend_id  from my_friends where first_user_id=1 and approved=1
union
SELECT  second_user_id user_id ,first_user_id friend_id from my_friends where second_user_id=1 and approved=1
```

and when I check explain plan for this , this throws

**EXPLAIN PLAN ERROR**

```
Error
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

I am using this query in most of the queries as a subquery and this one causing the issue to check explain plan for all other queries

Comment: Does the query itself work? What versions of MySQL have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and yes the query is working . I am using MYSQL that comes with WAMP and the version :- 5.1.53-community-log  . Thanks again

Comment: I suggest filing a MySQL bug. They can mark it as a dup if they decide that it is one. There have certainly been _similar_ bugs before (though IIRC most were resolved as "can't fix until 6.0 because it's too complex").

Comment: thanks for your help and I will do that .Any other work around you can think of .. Changing table structure or any other ?

Comment: Your table structure looks good to me. Even if I could think of a workaround, I wouldn't recommend it: your table structure being correct is the most important thing, and it already is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Mysql and raised with mysql